# Hazelcast Jet internal optimization

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I examine the Hazelcast Jet for my project needs, but I found the documentation really vague regarding the following topics:

1) When I perform a data join on two list streams...like for example:

```java
BatchStage<Trade> trades = p.drawFrom(list("trades"));
BatchStage<Entry<Integer, Broker>> brokers =    
p.drawFrom(list("brokers"));
BatchStage<Tuple2<Trade, Broker>> joined = trades.hashJoin(brokers,
    joinMapEntries(Trade::brokerId),
    Tuple2::tuple2);
joined.drainTo(Sinks.logger());
```

then can I somehow tell Jet what join underneath will actually occur? 
Either map-side join or reduce side join...? I mean just imagine the "brokers" set to be small and the trades set to be really huge. Optimal technique to perform the join of these two sets is map-side join aka broadcast join....What data will be transferred over network when Jet will do the join? Are there any size based optimization?

2) I was testing the following scenario:

easy pipeline:

```java
private Pipeline createPipeLine() {
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
    BatchStage stage = p.drawFrom(Sources.<Date>list("master"));
    stage.drainTo(Sinks.logger());
    return p;
}
```

`list("master")` is being constantly filled by another node in the cluster. Now when I submit this pipeline to cluster, only subset of the list("master") is drained to logger. Can I somehow set the Jet job to be constantly draining the `list("master")` to standard output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at the [reference manual?](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.7/manual/#hash-join)

Answer (score 2):

1. From Javadoc of HashJoin:

   Implementationally, the hash-join transform is optimized for throughput
   so that each computing member has a local copy of all the enriching
   data, stored in hashtables (hence the name). The enriching streams are
   consumed in full before ingesting any data from the primary stream.

   For your example, all the items from `broker` list will be consumed first from all members then `trades` list will be consumed.
2. `IList` is a batch source, you need a streaming source to continuously consume the items. You can use `IQueue` as a source, here is an easy way to create a source for a queue:

   ```
   StreamSource<Trade> queueSource = SourceBuilder.<IQueue<Trade>>stream("queueStream", 
           c -> c.jetInstance().getHazelcastInstance().getQueue("trades"))
       .<Trade>fillBufferFn((queue, buf) -> buf.add(queue.poll()))
       .build();
   ```

Comment: 2. Regarding IList, I missed that it's batch source only, I apologize.

Comment: I was successfull with IMap configuring it as StreamSource then, works as expected. 1. "each computing member has a local copy of all the enriching data" This is very usefull information in terms of howto design the Pipeline job according to the size of processed data. Thank you.

Comment: [This blog post](https://blog.hazelcast.com/ways-to-enrich-stream-with-jet/) might also give you some insight on how to work with joins/enrichment.